# Symfony Validator, validating properties defined in Traits

Tags: symfony, symfony-validator

I'm developing a project in Symfony 2.8.

Suppose you have this scenario, with Class ClassA using Trait TraitA which provides a property you would like to validate, and **you do not want to edit TraitA** because it is in an external library (e.g. a Doctrine Behaviour, as in https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors).

Suppose **you want to use Annotations** to validate your class ClassA, throught the Symfony Validator (https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html)

How can you accomplish this? These are the classes.

```
Class ClassA {
    use TraitA
}

Trait TraitA {
    private $property_in_trait_a;
}
```

The following is the only solution I found, that possibly generates a violation mapped to the entire class (i need to specify error_mapping in the related Form to target the right field on the form):

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

Class ClassA {
    use TraitA

    /**
     * Fake method only used to validate $property_in_trait_a
     * 
     * @Assert\Something()
     * 
     */
    public function getPropertyInTraitA()
    {
         return $this->property_in_trait_a;
    }
}
```

is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: what's dirty in this approach if you can't change the Trait? then you can only a) extend the trait or b) overwrite the attribute in your using class or c) manipulate the getter like you did it. but at someplace you need to annotate it if annotations are your way.

Comment: Either what @LBA suggessted or fall back to using `YAML` files to specify validations...

Comment: In doctrine  there are @AttributeOverrides annotations http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/override-field-association-mappings-in-subclasses.html I was wondering if in Symfony exists something like those.